# Update total in table row with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have a table

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="quantity" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="total" disabled />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="quantity" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="total" disabled />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="quantity" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="total" disabled />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="quantity" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="total" disabled />
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I update the total input field when a change in quantity or price happens?

I have thought of something like

```
$('table tbody tr td').filter(':nth-child(1), :nth-child(2)').children('input').change(function() {
    $(this).parent('td').siblings('td').filter(':nth-child(3)').val(?);
});
```

but it seems a bit unhandy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much easy to read and control if you can assign some dummy class to quantity, price and total input.

Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty" name="quantity" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="prc" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="total" name="total" disabled />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty" name="quantity" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="prc" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="total" name="total" disabled />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty" name="quantity" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="prc" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="total" name="total" disabled />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty" name="quantity" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="prc" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="total" name="total" disabled />
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
$('table tbody tr').find('.qty, .prc').on('keyup',function() {

    var parent = $(this).parents('tr');
    var quantity = parseInt(parent.find('.qty').val())||0;
    var price = parseInt(parent.find('.prc').val())||0;

    parent.find('.total').val(quantity*price);


});
```

Check working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vmndhh1a/30/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$('table tbody tr td').find('input').keyup(function() {
  var total=0;
  total=(parseInt($(this).parent('td').siblings('td').not(':nth-child(3)').find('input').val())||0)+(parseInt($(this).val())||0);
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input:last').val(total)
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s07zad63/)**

Answer (score 1):

Personally, i prefer not to select elements by their position. If you wind up changing them later, or adding another your code is broken.
I would do something like:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=total]').val(?);
```